# Ordinary differential equation .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The roots of the auxiliary equation for a homogeneous linear differential equation with real constant coefficients that has $ y= 4 + 2x^2 - e ^{-3x}$  as a particular solution are :

1) $ m= 0 , 0 , 0, -3 $

2) $m = 0 , 0 , 2 , -3 $

3) $m=4 , 0 , 0 , 3 $

4) $ m= 0 ,0 ,0 ,3 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auxiliary equation of the homogeneous linear differential equation
$$a_n y^{(n)} + a_{n-1} y^{(n-1)} + \cdots + a_1 y' + a_0 y = 0$$
is 
$$a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 = 0.$$
For every non-repeated root $r$, add $Ce^{rt}$ to the solution. For repeated roots $r$ with multiplicity $m$, add 
$$C_{m-1}t^{m-1}e^{rt} + C_{m-2}t^{m-2}e^{rt} + \cdots + C_0t^0e^{rt}$$
to the solution. Rewriting the solution slightly,
$$y = 4t^0e^{0t} + 0t^1e^{0t} + 2t^2e^{0t} - e^{-3t}.$$
Now it is a matter of reading off the exponents.

Comment: N.B. As a slight technicality issue, the answer to the multiple choice is the smallest possible set of roots of the auxiliary equation. It is very well possible that other terms are nullified by initial data.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The solution, for all we know, could have also been $$y = 4t^0e^{0t} + 0t^1e^{0t} + 2t^2e^{0t} - e^{-3t} + 0e^{4t} + 0e^{\pi t} + 0e^{12t},$$
giving us $\{0,0,0,-3,4,\pi,12\}$ as the roots of the auxiliary. The question writer should have been more observant :-)

Comment: Yeah.This question was asked in a competitive exam.Thanks for your answer.